# Connect Data Studio to PostgreSQL that is in GCP VPC network

Tags: database, postgresql, google-cloud-platform, looker-studio

How can we do that? I have tried adding in Data Studio address to the route and firewall but still doesn't work. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: This question does not seem to be related to programming, so I think it is not suitable for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database should be publicly available (internet level) to be accessible from Data Studio.  The fact of being in GCP VPC network changes nothing.

If your database is behind a firewall, you need to add some IP ranges as exception to make it work (notice they're using [CIDR notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing), so `64.18.0.0/20` means all IPs from `64.18.0.0` to `64.18.15.255`):

```
64.18.0.0/20
64.233.160.0/19
66.102.0.0/20
66.249.80.0/20
72.14.192.0/18
74.125.0.0/16
108.177.8.0/21
173.194.0.0/16
207.126.144.0/20
209.85.128.0/17
216.58.192.0/19
216.239.32.0/19
```

These ranges are described in https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7288010

If your firewall does not use CIDR notation by default and you are not used to CIDR notation, use [this tool](https://www.ipaddressguide.com/cidr) to convert CIDR notation to IP Range.

Comment: That's the solution with postgres. But keep in ming that's not a good solution. Indeed, you need to allowlist all the Google IP ranges. And thus, any other (malicious?) user will be able to use the same ranges by using Google product (such as Datastudio, which is free). There is better solutions if you can migrate to MySQL, but with postgres it's a security risk to assume with you use the datastudio connector.

Comment: Currently, it is the supported solution. Because Data Studio is free, Google makes no commitment from where the connection comes from (it can come from anywhere inside its network). If security is still a concern, you should not be using Data Studio at all, but I think you're OK if you use other security measures as well (encryption, strong passwords, updated software, etc). In my opinion, securing a database with a firewall is an old and sad way to protect data (internet is the rule, servers should be used to be globally accessible and they should implement modern security measures).

Comment: I agree with you, I hate the IP world. But in this case, you haven't other solutions... I have one in mind, I need to test it before going further

Comment: I think its a waste of time to dig for better solutions. The better is to stop using conventional databases like PostgreSQL/MySQL directly connected with BI tools (they just work, but they don't play well together). BigQuery plays really nice with DataStudio, so you should consider to build a ETL job to populate BigQuery from your sources, then connect it to DataStudio.